# How and when to break knock up cc with cleanse dash?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have read that you can break the knock up cc by using cleanse and following that with a dash. My question is in two parts;

1. In what part of the knock up animation should i use the cleanse/qss
   and also when should I use my dash.
2. Which abilities count as dash I mean I know of
   lucian and graves e those are dashes but do abilities like yasuo e
   and irelia's q which need a target count as a dash for breaking the
   duration of the knock up cc?

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found that you have to **use your Cleanse effect and your flash at exactly the same time**. This will allow you to get out of any Knockup as seen in the video:

Now one thing to note is that I don't know if this is working as intended. I've heard from various sources that the intention of knockups is that their duration cannot be lowered. However I can hardly think of something like this going past Riot without noticing during 2 patches.

For your second part: For me it only worked with flash so far but I haven't tested any other spells yet. However I think that real "Dashes" Like Lucian or Graves E won't work but "Flashes" will (Kassa R, Ezreal E etc)

Comment: Seems like a undocumented feature... aka bug. It also requires 2 things to be off cooldown at the same time.

Comment: considering the meta shift I think it would be well worth knowing, I will try out the suggestion with some friends later hopefully it works also I read this briefly on wikia league of legends they did not go in-depth in how which is why I wanted clarity on how it is done

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Well yeah It seems kind of unintended, however often things like this are just classiefied as a "Feature" and riot has done this quite often before (Like the one time where it allowed people to play One For All through mods. This even got implemented later on)

Answer (score 0):

Knock-ups are intended to be unable to be interrupted or broken out of - same goes for knock-backs. There is no way to cancel a displacement ability (knock-up, -back, or a pull), at least not intentionally, and champions with those mechanics (hint: a certain cow) are balanced around the fact that, aside from spell-shields, those mechanics **cannot** be mitigated.

In the event of finding a way to circumvent this mechanic, you are likely finding a bug. Requiring two things to be done "at once" (i.e, a cleanse and a dash) is most certainly a bug.

There are certain instances where you can animation cancel one of these mechanics (i.e, Ezreal's Arcane Shift on a Blitzcrank grab). These are widely considered to be bugs.. or at the very least, an oddity.

Comment: Strongly disagree with the fact that the Ezreal Q used to jump out of a Blitz hook is a bug. This has been possible for 4 years now and is one of the reasons why Ezreal is a popular ADC Pick against Blitzcrank. If this really was a bug riot would've removed it since its existance is extremely game-changing. IIRC They also did a statement on it. I'll try to find it.